# Shortcut for WPF text in Binding attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

The following text repeats itself a lot in the my XAML files, with a change of only the `ConverterParameter`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextResource, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=MyText }">
```

Is it possible to create a shortcut for it?

Maybe something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{MyBinding Param=MyText }">
```

It can improve readability, and help make mass-changes in case of converter name change.

Comment: Have a look at `MarkupExtensions`, you should be able to create somthing similar to what you need. http://tech.pro/tutorial/883/wpf-tutorial-fun-with-markup-extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom binding:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public String Param {
        get {return this.ConverterParameter.ToString();}
        set {this.ConverterParameter = value;}

    }

    // usage: Text="{local:MyBinding Param=MyText}"
    public MyBinding() : base("TextResource")
    {
        this.Converter = new MyConverter();
    }

    // usage: Text="{local:MyBinding MyText}"
    public MyBinding(string param) : base("TextResource")
    {
        this.Converter = new MyConverter();
        this.Param = param;
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{local:MyBinding MyText1}" />
<TextBlock Text="{local:MyBinding Param=MyText2}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom MarkupExtension.
There's an excellent tutorial on MarkupExtension on CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140618/WPF-Tutorial-TypeConverter-Markup-Extension

Your extension would look something like:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
public class MyBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly string _key;

    public MyBindingExtension(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // TODO: your code here to retrieve the converted value.
    }
}
```